# Bottom Banner Shifts Up Into Content Area

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, screen-resolution

I have now validated both html & css using w3, but when i try to test it in different screen resolutions the bottom banner always shifts up into the content area. This also happens when i have all the toolbars on in Internet Explorer 8. It seems to work better in Firefox using my 1280x1024 monitor. I know it is a css problem, but unable to correct it. It would be good to get some help in this matter.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<!-- saved from url=(0017)http://localhost/ -->
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>My Test Site</title>
<meta content="" name="description">
<meta content="," name="keywords">
<meta content="index, nofollow" name="robots">
<meta content="" name="google-site-verification">
<link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
<link href="favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png"><!--[if gt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie8.css" />
<![endif]-->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"      
<type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.panel').click(function () {

            $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

            current = $(this);

            $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 50);              

            return false;
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
            resizePanel();
    });

});

function resizePanel() {

    width = $(window).width();
    height = $(window).height();

    mask_width = width * $('.item').length;

    $('#debug').html(width  + ' ' + height + ' ' + mask_width);

    $('#wrapper, .item').css({width: width, height: height});
    $('#mask').css({width: mask_width, height: height});
    $('#wrapper').scrollTo($('a.selected').attr('href'), 0);
    }        
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="mask">
<div class="item" id="item1"><a class="img" href="/"><img alt=""   
id="logo" name="logo" src="http://i50.tinypic.com/nghgg.png"></a>
<div id="top_banner"><script type="text/javascript">
                pb_cid='BAYBANNER468X60_1';
                pb_type='banner_468x60';
</script> <script src="http://clkads.com/banners/script/include_img_banner.js"    
type="text/javascript">
</script></div>
<div id="navwrapper">
<ul class="floatleft" id="nav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
<br class="clear"></div>
<div id="left_banner"><script type="text/javascript">
                pb_cid='BAYBANNER120X600_1';
                pb_type='banner_120x600';
</script> <script src="http://clkads.com/banners/script/include_img_banner.js"  
type="text/javascript">
</script></div>
<div class="content">
<div id="right_banner"><script type="text/javascript">
                    pb_cid='BAYBANNER120X600_1';
                    pb_type='banner_120x600';
</script> <script src="http://clkads.com/banners/script/include_img_banner.js"   
type="text/javascript">
</script></div>
<div id="bottom_banner"><script type="text/javascript">
                    pb_cid='BAYBANNER728X90_2';
                    pb_type='banner_728x90';
</script><script src="http://clkads.com/banners/script/include_img_banner.js" 
type="text/javascript">
</script></div>
<div class="right_arrow"><a class="panel" href="#item2"><img alt="arrow" height="24"   
src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rcy1zp.png" width="24"></a></div>
<div id="footer">Copyright 2012 All Rights Reserved | <a href="">Privacy Policy</a> | 
<a href="">Terms of Use</a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item" id="item2">
<div class="content">
<div class="left_arrow"><a class="panel" href="#item1"><img alt="arrow" 
height="24"     
src="http://i49.tinypic.com/2i7obnq.png" width="24"></a></div>
<div class="right_arrow"><a class="panel" href="#item3"><img alt="arrow"    
height="24"     
src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rcy1zp.png" width="24"></a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item" id="item3">
<div class="content">
<div class="left_arrow"><a class="panel" href="#item2"><img alt="arrow" height="24"    
src="http://i49.tinypic.com/2i7obnq.png" width="24"></a></div>
<div class="right_arrow"><a class="panel" href="#item4"><img alt="arrow"   
height="24"     
src="http://i48.tinypic.com/2rcy1zp.png" width="24"></a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
body {
height : 100%;
width : 100%;
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
overflow : hidden;
}
#wrapper {
width : 100%;
height : 100%;
position : absolute;
top : 0;
left : 0;
background-color : #ffffff;
overflow : hidden;
}
#mask {
width : 500%;
height : 100%;
background-color : #ffffff;
}
.item {
width : 20%;
height : 100%;
float : left;
background-color : #b4d8e7;
}
.content {
width : 969px;
height : 590px;
margin : 0 auto;
background-color : #000000;
position : relative;
top : 125px;
}
.selected {
background : #fff;
font-weight : 700;
}
.clear {
clear : both;
}
a img {
border : none;
display : block;
}
a {
outline : 0;
}
html {
overflow : auto;
}

#navwrapper {
background-color:#000;
left:0;
top:80px;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
}

#nav {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
padding-top:4px;
}

#nav,#nav ul {
list-style:none;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#nav a {
display:block;
color:#ccc;
text-decoration:none;
padding:7px;
}

#nav a.dmenu:hover {
color:#36C !important;
background-color:#fff !important;
}

#nav li {
float:left;
position:static;
width:auto;
}

#nav li ul {
position:absolute;
display:none;
margin-left:-1px;
padding-bottom:10px;
background-color:#FFF;
border:1px solid #bbb;
border-top:none;
box-shadow:0 0 5px #ddd;
z-index:5000;
}

#nav li:hover a,#nav a:focus,#nav a:active {
color:#fff;
background:#444;
text-decoration:none;
padding:7px;
}

#nav li ul,#nav ul li {
width:10em;
}

#nav ul li a {
color:#36C !important;
border-right:0;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
color:#36C !important;
background-color:#eef3fb !important;
border-right:0;
}

#nav li:hover ul {
display:block;
}

#nav li:hover ul a {
color:#000;
background-color:transparent;
}

#nav ul a:hover {
background-color:#606060 !important;
color:#FFF !important;
}

.menuseprator {
border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
margin:10px 0;
}

.arrowdown {
font-size:0.5em;
}

.floatleft {
float:left;
}

.floatright {
float:right;
}

.clear {
clear:both;
}

#top_banner {
width : 468px;
height : 60px;
right : 1px;
position : fixed;
overflow : hidden;
padding : 10px;
}
#left_banner {
width : 120px;
height : 600px;
left : 1px;
top : 110px;
position : fixed;
overflow : hidden;
padding : 10px;
}
#right_banner {
width : 120px;
height : 600px;
right : 1px;
top : 110px;
position : fixed;
overflow : hidden;
padding : 10px;
}
#bottom_banner {
bottom : 50px;
right : 260px;
height : 90px;
width : 728px;
position : fixed;
z-index : 999;
margin : 0;
}
.right_arrow {
height : 24px;
width : 24px;
right : 0;
bottom : -30px;
border : none;
position : absolute;
padding : 0;
}
.left_arrow {
height : 24px;
width : 24px;
left : 0;
bottom : -30px;
border : none;
position : absolute;
padding : 0;
}
#logo {
left : 10px;
top : 8px;
border : 0;
height : 64px;
width : 64px;
position : fixed;
}
#footer {
bottom : 5px;
left : 476px;
font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size : 11px;
text-align : center;
color : #6e6e6e;
position : fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your (over)use of `position: fixed`. Position fixed should not be used for general site layout. It does not work well with different resolution browsers and generally will cause issues. At most, it should be used to attach a bar to the top or bottom of the screen.

Your issue is an underlying one and requires a bit of a redesign of your CSS.

Comment: Thanks 4 your speedy reply smdrager. I have used position: fixed for the horizontal layout so that the navbar & creatives are only loaded once, making the site load faster.